# How to remove line break from Base64 encoded string?

Tags: java, android, base64

I was trying to remove line breaks, but with this code below I can't proceed to remove it with `replace()` method.

```java
private String encryptBase64(String data){
    byte[] values = null;

    try{
        values = data.getBytes("UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String encrypted = Base64.encodeToString(values, Base64.DEFAULT);
        encrypted.replace("\r\n", "");
    Log.i("base64", encrypted);
    return encrypted;
}
```

As the code above, it's clear that I tried to remove line breaks but the code failed to do it. How to remove the line breaks?

Screenshot : [image: base64 Log]

Comment: Because strings are immutable - you're calling `replace` but ignoring the return value. That's got nothing to do with Android or base64 - it's just how Java strings work.

Comment: I did replace and not replace the string. There's no differences..

Comment: lol. I did that before, but doesn't solve my issue. I though it was different case, so I made a question here.

Comment: I DID post my "reasonable" code that doesn't work. Have you tried by yourself?

Comment: sometimes, its look same but its different. Think again before you talk.

Comment: There's nothing reasonable about calling `replace()` and ignoring the return value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solution for your problem , You have to use URLEncoder to encode such string to pass in url.
Example :

```
private String encryptBase64(String data){
byte[] values = null;
try{
    values = data.getBytes("UTF-8");
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
String encrypted = Base64.encodeToString(values, Base64.DEFAULT);
// encrypted.replace("\r\n", "");
Log.i("base64", encrypted);
// =========== use this line of code ===============
    try {
            url_encode_val = URLEncoder.encode(encrypted, "utf-8");
            Log.e("encryptData_To url::", url_encode_val);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

return url_encode_val;
}
```

Comment: its work! wow. I'm impressed.. Thanks a lot Amit, god bless you

Comment: i'm happy it was helpful to you .. happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `encrypted = encrypted.replaceAll("(\\r|\\n|\\r\\n)+", "");` instead of `encrypted.replace("\n", "");`

Comment: nothing happens

Comment: you try with `replaceAll` function?

Comment: i did, but still same

Comment: @KevinBradley try with editted answer.

Comment: same thing, thanks for helping me. I think I need to close this question.

Comment: @KevinBradley Give a shot to my answer ;)

Comment: it doesnt work for me

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is:

```
String stringAsProfImg = android.util.Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayOfImg, android.util.Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Or what I am doing is converting a bitmap image to byte array and then converting byte array to BASE64 String.

Below is an example:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
                byteArrayOfImg = stream.toByteArray();
                bitmapImage.recycle();
                bitmapImage = null;
                stringAsProfImg =android.util.Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayOfImg, android.util.Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Comment: compress to JPEG? you god damn right